# Trying to create random style gallery of images

Tags: jquery, html, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create an almost random grid of images, similar to this site, https://evanpjenkins.com, although I'm not exactly sure of the best way to approach it

My first instinct was to use a Flexbox grid, with positioning inside the cells, which does work to a certain degree but it's still row based so I would have to set negative margins in order to get overlapping.

```
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-padding-y small-up-1 medium-up-2">
  {% for picture in page.images %}
   {% if picture.aspect-ratio == "7-5" %}
   <div class="cell align-self-bottom">

   <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 cell">
     {% assign image = picture.image %}
     <div class="image--7-5" data-interchange="{% include images/interchange-img-small-12-medium-12-cell.html %}"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   </div>
   {% elsif picture.aspect-ratio == "5-7" %}
   <div class="cell">
   {% assign image = picture.image %}
   <div class="image--5-7" data-interchange="{% include images/interchange-img-small-12-medium-12-cell.html %}"></div>
   </div>
   {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```